# Failure of cx_Oracle underneath pip command fails on python27

Tags: python, pip, cx-oracle

version: python2.7

attempting to install cx_oracle

> Collecting cx_Oracle Using cached cx_Oracle-5.3.tar.gz Complete output from command python setup.py Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in  File "C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\cx-Oracle\setup.py", line 190, in  raise DistutilsSetupError(message) distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate Oracle include files in C:\new_software\Oracle\instantclient_12_1 Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\cx-Oracle\

I have installed oracle client 12_1 and set Oracle Home and PATH variables on Windows10.

python2.7 is installed and within `python27/scripts/` , I see `pip.exe`

I get below error when i tried running:

> C:\new_software\Python27\Scripts>pip install cx_Oracle failed to create process.

Request help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check that `C:\new_software\Oracle\instantclient_12_1` actually has the include (`.h`) files?

Comment: no i don't see it.

Comment: Currently facing the below error: cx_Oracle.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _OCISessionPoolCreate referenced in function _SessionPool_Init
    build\lib.win32-2.7-12c\cx_Oracle.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 109 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\User1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

Answer (score 2):

For cx_Oracle 5.x you need to have the SDK package of the instant client installed on your machine in order to build.

cx_Oracle 6.x, however, doesn't require that package at all. In fact, binary wheels are available so you don't need to compile anything at all! You can install the first beta of this version by using this command:

`pip install cx_Oracle --pre`

You can also download and install a pre-compiled binary from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle).

Comment: Thanks Anthony, happy to hear from creator of cx_Oracle. I got past that issue, and then had to install Visual c++ after that it still fails with the error. I have updated the question with new error. request your help.

Comment: \instantclient_12_1\sdk\lib\msvc/LIBPATH:C:\new_software\Python27\PC\VS9.0 oci.lib /EXPORT:initcx_Oracle build\temp.win32-2.712c\cx_Oracle.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-2.7-12c\Release\src\cx_Oracle.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win32-2.7-12c\Release\src\cx_Oracle.pyd.manifest Creating library build\temp.win32-2.7-12c\Release\src\cx_Oracle.lib and object build\temp.win32-2.7-12c\Release\src\cx_Oracle.exp
    cx_Oracle.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _OCIAttrGet referenced in function _Error_InternalNew

Comment: cx_Oracle.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _OCISessionPoolCreate referenced in function _SessionPool_Init
    build\lib.win32-2.7-12c\cx_Oracle.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 109 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\User1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

Comment: I updated my answer to suggest that you download and install a precompiled binary. :-)

Comment: Thanks @Anthony Tuininga. I was able to install it successfully. But getting the below error and i already see a post of yours: https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/15  let me try setting LD_LIBPATH from my end. pls let me know of any thoughts. cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: Tried setting PATH for instantclient_12_1 folder -> 1. at folder level, 2./VC12 3./oci.dll  still getting same error. pls let me know.

Comment: That error suggests you are mixing 64-bit and 32-bit. Python, cx_Oracle and Oracle Instant Client must all be either 64-bit or all 32-bit.